# Compiling C on macos-catalina

Tags: c, macos-catalina

I have developed a quite large Fortran program on Windows that calls some C routines for character input.  I provide a makefile for compiling this program also on various Unix dialects and MacOS.  I just upgraded the Mac I use for testing to Catalina and the compilation of the C routine failed, it cannot find all the (for me) mysterious libraries "sys/ioctl.h" "signal.h" etc. This worked on the previous MacOS version Mojave.

I had (while using Mojave) installed the gfortran with gcc and I have compiler flag -DBSD to select some of the necessary C system libraries.  I have other flags for Linux and Cygwin.

I do not use the Mac myself but there are some users of my program with Mac so I want to keep them happy.  How should I modify my makefile?

Comment: By writing one. Seriously where is your existing makefile

Comment: I do not think the makefile will make any difference.  But I should probably ask how to compile a C program om Catalina.  However, I do not know how to write a C program.  In my Fotran program I use a function getkey.c I found on the web which can read a single character which I use on Linux and MacOS to allow command line editing.  As far as I know there is no Fortran facility for that.

Comment: Quote - " How should I modify my makefile?" - Where is the makefile to modify?

Comment: For me the problem is that a makefile I have used for some years is broken on MacOS Cataline.  If I change the question to be how do I compile a C program that is not really my primary interest.  I found that if I write a one line C program and tried to compile I get the same error message: warning: no include path in which to search for stdio.h.  So the question is where has this path disappeared in the new MacOS?

Comment: The MAC install does NOT include the C header files and libraries.  They need to be installed separately.  From the web page [install c environment](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_environment_setup.htm)  "If you use Mac OS X, the easiest way to obtain GCC is to download the Xcode development environment from Apple's web site and follow the simple installation instructions. Once you have Xcode setup, you will be able to use GNU compiler for C/C++."

Xcode is currently available at developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/."

Comment: I have obviously installed Xcode earlier and MacOS does not flag it as needed in the update but after some digging I found an update and I hope that will work.  What a mess

Comment: It did not.  Do I have to install gfortran/gcc etc again also?

Comment: I managed to find a previous question about "Can't compile a C program on Mac after upgrading to Catalina" (and Mojave) which just made me more confused.  I guess it is time to give up support for Mac

Answer (score 1):

As I found out from the answers to "can't compile a C program on Mac ..." Apple is obviously not interested to have any other software than its own on the Mac.  Rather than trying to understand the various options to change the dirctory structure /usr/include and /usr/local/include to use GCC I decided to use the C compiler Apple provides in my Makefile.  So just changing from "gcc" to "cc" and removing some compiler options not available in the Apple C compiler I managed to compile my program.
I guess I am lucky having just two small C routines, trying to compile something more complex would require more understanding of MacOS than I am interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question in researching how I might compile an old 32 bit game for Catalina. I also discovered that Catalina removes some of the existing `/usr/include` structure which GCC expects, and that it is necessary to create a few symbolic links as well as copy some of the overarching structure in order to modify a header.

Much of the GCC source comes from GNU, so I might expect some incompatibilities, but this may help others who come across this question: https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/10/12/compiling-gcc-macos/

Archived version (3rd Nov 2019): http://web.archive.org/web/20191103040729/https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/10/12/compiling-gcc-macos/